# Building Yext.com Using RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, web-services, api

We are trying to build one website as    "http://www.yext.com/"

Brief about Yext --- This is like SEO where users owning business first check if there business is present in sites like yahoo-local.com, yelp,superpages, and many more .........  yext will show the available listings and also not available listings......

then on one click this will put your business listings on all the websites i.e yahoo local ,yelp,superpages etc...
you can check this functionality from yext.com for getting more info....

our job is to use API 's provided by all the websites i.e yahoo,yelp,superpages,whitepages.etc..... and to interface with RoR...

But we have a doubt that API'S  what we know are platform dependent so how to use them ?
can all the yahoo,superpages,yellowpages, and all the other websites API'S listed in yext  Support RoR? IF NOT what will be the possible alternative for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. APIs do not have to "support" Rails. APIs are a way for service providers, such as Yahoo, to expose services & datas to 3rd parties. As the "3rd party" you'll have to make your Rails app use these APIs...

Comment: Which protocols does this APIs use? SOAP?

Comment: ok... can i use webservices provided by these sites and using soap protocol can i retrieve and post the business listing information to those sites?

Comment: You may want to consider changing the title of this question since it doesn't help describe the problem you're trying to solve at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as whatever API has a Ruby client or you feel comfortable writing your own, then you should be able to integrate with them.